# LimeSurvey use JSON string from Database

Tags: mysql, json, pdo

When I use the admin tool for LimeSurvey to add an additional field to my survey, the attributedescriptions field in the database looks like this;

```
a:1:
{   
    s:11:"attribute_1";
    a:4:
    {
        s:11:"description";
        s:4:"Unit";
        s:9:"mandatory";
        s:1:"N";
        s:13:"show_register";
        s:1:"N";
        s:7:"cpdbmap";
        s:0:"";
    }
}
```

When I enter another, the field in the database looks like this;

```
a:2:
{
    s:11:"attribute_1";
    a:4:
    {
        s:11:"description";
        s:4:"Unit";
        s:9:"mandatory";
        s:1:"N";
        s:13:"show_register";
        s:1:"N";
        s:7:"cpdbmap";
        s:0:"";
    }

    s:11:"attribute_2";
    a:4:
    {
        s:11:"description";
        s:9:"Something";
        s:9:"mandatory";
        s:1:"N";
        s:13:"show_register";
        s:1:"N";
        s:7:"cpdbmap";
        s:0:"";
    }
}
```

I now need a dynamic way to get the words "Unit" and "Something" in to an array that I can use.

This is my code to get the json string;

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print $result[0]["attributedescriptions"];
```

I am terrible at PDO. I have tried;

```
$result = var_dump(json_decode($result[0]["attributedescriptions"], true);

$result = var_dump(json_decode($result["attributedescriptions"], true);

$result = var_dump(json_decode($result[0], true);
```

I get the error;

```
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/surveys/survey-admin/functions/functions.php on line 189 NULL
```

Comment: That's not JSON, it does look like PHP-`serialize()`ed data. Use `unserialize()` instead of `json_decode()`, and try again :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not** JSON, it is serialized data:

**serialize:**

```
$serialized_data = base64_encode(serialize($data));
```

**unserialize:**

```
$unserialized_data = unserialize(base64_decode($serialized_data));
```

`base64_encode()` is used to avoid corruption, if data is corrupted `unserialize()` will return false.

Comment: Ok, so when I do unserialize($result[0]['attributedescriptions']); I do get an array. But if I use base64_decode() as well... It just returns blank. Not even an empty array..